# How to update in ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Im trying to update my already existing entries using angularjs and ionic.I have two views, in the first view I have listed the car name and its model name. When the car name is selected, it is directed to second view  where the information regarding the selected car name and its models are listed so that they are edited and updated.I have declared `$rootScope.selectItem=key;` which help to show what is the selected car name. I face problem in update so, I need help in updating the information by replacing the new information with old information.

view 1:

```
 <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-model="carBrand" ng-repeat="name in carSelect">
        <button ng-click="selectItem(name)">{{name.name}}</button>                              
        <div class="item" ng-repeat="type in name.types">{{type}}</div>
 </ion-item>
 </ion-list>
```

view 2:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="newName"><br> Select Type:{{selectItem}}</div>
<ion-checkbox ng-repeat="field in fields" ng-model="field.checked" ng-checked="field.checked">
        {{field.name}}
</ion-checkbox>        
<button ng-click="remove()">Delete</button>
<button ng-click="Update()">Update</button></div>
```

Controller:

```
carService.controller('carBrand', ['$scope', 'carRepository', '$rootScope', '$state', '$stateParams', function ($scope, carRepository, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams) {
  $rootScope.carSelect = carRepository.data;
  $scope.newCarList = [];
  $scope.selectItem = function (key) {
    $rootScope.selectItem=key;
    $state.go('app.carModel');
  }

   carService.controller('carAdd', ['$scope', '$rootScope', '$state', function ($scope, $rootScope, $state) {
  $scope.newName = "";
  $scope.fields = [{ id: 1, name: 'Regular' },
    { id: 2, name: 'SUV' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Oversize' },
    { id: 4, name: 'Truck' },
    { id: 5, name: 'Motorcycle' }];

  $scope.sample = [];
  $scope.Update = function () {
    var carType = [];
....}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would change some things to make it more application-like.

First of all, change your state routing:

```
$stateProvider.state("app.carModel", {
    // ..
    url: "edit/:id"
}
```

Then in your selectedItem function:

```
$scope.selectItem = function (car) {
    // assuming your cars have an id property
    // you can ofcourse also use something else
    $state.go('app.carModel', { id: car.id });
}
```

Then in your edit/add controller:

```
carService.controller('carAdd', ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'carRepository', function ($scope, $stateParams, carRepository) {
    var carId = $stateParams.id;

    // make a copy, so it only gets changed in the repository when the user
    // presses 'Update'
    $scope.car = angular.copy(carRepository.get(carId));

    $scope.fields = [{ id: 1, name: 'Regular' },
        { id: 2, name: 'SUV' },
        { id: 3, name: 'Oversize' },
        { id: 4, name: 'Truck' },
        { id: 5, name: 'Motorcycle' }
    ];

    $scope.sample = [];
    $scope.Update = function () {
        // ..
        // in the save function replace the existing with the edited
        carRepository.save($scope.car);
    }
}
```